# Well-documented, Open Source and Fast C/C++ image manipulation library. Like 'resize', rotate, change color, crop

Tags: c++, c, graphics, image-processing

Looking for a bunch of ***optimized*** image processing utility functions. Like: Resize with Cubic Interpolation, Rotate, Crop, Change a Color to a different Color. Much like what the GIMP has. But without the license and bloat of The GIMP.

- Must be Free and Open Source, preferably not GPL, *unless it is **best***
- Must have comprehensive / good documentation for beginners (to image processing).
- Must be faster than ImageMagick, or any of its forks (GraphicsMagick).
- Must include a bunch of '**actual algorithms**', in the vein of a image manipulator like The Gimp. Not just a bunch scientific algorithms for which I have no use.

...

- Doesn't need to support image file formats (e.g. import from a GIF).
- Doesn't need to support more than 24-bit color.
- Doesn't need to be *the fastest*, but speed needs to be better than academic.

### Answer

I am using ImageMagick (or Magick++ its library) to render the final GIF animation because it is relatively fast at doing so. For the rest, the operations are so simple that I am using the 'unofficial' GIF decoder library from sourceforge to decode to a array. Then, taking the array of raw image data and; **Crop / Color Change** in a standard C++ for-loop.

For True Super Optimized uses, it looks like other people on StackOverflow are recommending `OpenCV` or `Boost's GIL` (by Adobe). They both contain good primitives and `OpenCV` also contains alot more algorithms which are optimized for speed.

Comment: This question is very subjective and has no definitive answer. What is "super bloated"? What is "just a bunch of vertices"?

Comment: @Nicol I fixed these issues with an edit... Thanks. It's subjective because I have a very specific problem with GIFs and ImageMagick and slowness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question looks very subjective. Still look at the [Boost Generic Image Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/gil/doc/index.html), it is open source.

Comment: Thank you. However, in my case it was better to just use plain C and code it myself. Good enough to be marked answer still

Answer (score 1):

I really recommand you [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). If you want to use a lightweight library for manipulating an image, [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) will be also good choice.